# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start on IIS Server

Tags: iis, .net-core

When I am using PostgreSQL and MongoDB with .Net 5. It Working Perfectly on the local system. After Complete my project and deploy to the server.

Then Shows

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

almost all solutions try with my code and server.

Comment: "It Working Perfectly on the local system", so what's your local setup? IIS Express/VS is not IIS in many ways, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: i am enable iis in my system and hosted on there

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#50030-in-process-startup-failure "The cause of a process startup failure can usually be determined from **entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log**", so what did you get from the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Install [the proper runtime with the Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet)
2. Check DLL issue

   1. Navigate to the root directory and type `CMD` on the folder path bar:

      [image: Folder Path Bar]
   2. Type in command `dotnet {yourApplicationName}.dll`
   3. Open your browser and navigate to http://localhost:5000/

   If all is okay, your site will be working on the local host.
3. Exit CMD and Config in IIS

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sub-applications) to republish your app.